# Trouble with Paypal IPN adjusting Inventory

Tags: php, paypal, mysqli, paypal-ipn

Being new to PHP, mysqli, and paypalipn, I'm having some difficulty getting the Paypal IPN to adjust my inventory. However it doesn't seem to make the adjustments to the database.

What it's supposed to do is take the item_number, and size and reduce the inventory of that particular item. I apologize in advance for the horrible syntax that'll make most coders cringe. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// Update the inventory
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
    $id = $_POST['item_number'.$i];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'.$i];
    $size_find = $_POST['option_selection0'.$i];
    $size = 'size_'.$size_find;
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE `products` SET
        ".$size.",
        WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i',
        `$size` - $quantity,
        $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Have you checked IPN history to ensure the IPN is getting sent?  Have you checked your web server logs to see what (if any) error is occurring?

Comment: It doesn't update the database. Yes I've checked the IPN. I'll check the web servers log and check to see what they read. Is the syntax correct in this code?

Comment: Ok so the error is that "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" and also "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: option_selection01". I think the listener is having problems getting the option_selection0 variable. I've also tried os0_x, os0x and option_selection0_x with no avail. Anyone know the correct way to grab this variable?